# How can print out a list with json?

Tags: javascript, json, get

I need to print things out in json as a list so it appears like:

```
{
  "attendees": [
    "Kevin Tyler",
    "Syeda Shyra",
         ]
}
```

But as of right now, I have:

```
{
    "attendees": [
        {
            "attendee": "Kevin Tyler"
        },
        {
            "attendee": "Syeda Shyra"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm printing it out with this:

```
res.json({attendees: response.rows});
```

My database is below:

```
  attendee   |      workshop      
-------------+--------------------
 Ann Nowicki | React Fundamentals
 Ann Nowicki | TensorFlo
 Kevin Tyler | Biology 101
 Syeda Shyra | Biology 101
```

How can I make it where it doesn't list attendee for each person, and instead only says attendees once at the beginning?

If you need it, here is more of my code:

```
 30 app.get("/api", async (req,res) => {
 31 
 32 
 33         try {
 34                 // if there is an argument
 35                 // else there isn't
 36 
 37                 // find attendee
 38                 const template = "SELECT attendee FROM people WHERE workshop =$1";
 39                 const response = await pool.query(template, [req.query.workshop]);
 40 
 41                 console.log(response);
 42                 // can print
 43                 if (req.query.workshop!=null) {
 44                         if (response.rowCount!=0) {
 45                                   res.json({attendees: response.rows});
 46                          } else {
 47                                 res.json({"error": "workshop not found"});
 48                         }
 49 
 50                 } else {
 51                         const resp = await pool.query("SELECT workshop FROM people");
 52                         res.json({workshops: resp.rows});
 53                 }
 54 
 55 
 56         } catch (err) {
 57                 console.error("whoops " + err);
 58                 res.json({status:"error"});
 59         }
 60 
 61 
 62 });
```

Comment: Take a look at [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Answer (score 1):

You need to unwrap the contents of each `row`. Use `map` function to achieve that. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
res.json({attendees: response.rows.map(a=>a.attendee)});
```